# JMeter Non Gui Mode - Unable to run. Please advise

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a threadgroup with `no of threads = 30` and `ramp up = 1`. I have a single `transaction controller` inside this thread group. Inside `Transaction controller`, there is a `synchronizing timer` set to `5 users per group` and also multiple `module controllers` pointing to different `test fragments` residing under same test plan. Each of these `test fragments` contain a `transaction controller` and a `uniform random timer` set to `1000ms`.

I am trying to execute the script in non gui mode as follows

`jmeter -n -t [path of script] -l [path of output file]`

Test gets stopped and I see following messages in log file. Not sure why log shows 0 threads when I actually set the thread count to 30.

```
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary> 
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [ID] 
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [ID] 
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2017/03/08 17:00:32 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Running test (1489014033090) 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 0 threads for group Thread Group. 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 0 ramp-up 1 perThread Infinity delayedStart=false 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/03/08 17:00:33 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Please guide me where I am getting wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extra space is present before number of threads. in ThreadGroup. After I delete the space, Its working.